# Installing Uppaal on Mac OS

Tags: macos, installation, macos-catalina, uppaal

I'm trying to install Uppaal on my Mac. I have Catalina installed and I am aware of the workaround posted on here to do with authorisation and have done this.

But when I run the Uppaal script I get an error saying

> Error: Unable to access jarfile ./uppaal.jar

I can't figure out what the problem is or how to get around it. Java is up to date.

Help please, I need this for a uni assignment

Answer (score 0):

It seems that UPPAAL will give the above error, if run it from the GUI from a path containing a space.

I will report this to the development team, until they are able to fix it one of the following workaround:

- move the files to a path not containing any spaces (NB: the full path must not contain any spaces)

Answer (score 0):

open the uppaal batch file(e.g. by TextEditor) and add this command to the top of it:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same issue. Instead of adding `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` to the `uppaal` bash script, which is a bit intrusive, I changed line:

```sh
HERE=$(dirname "$(readlink -e $0)")
```

to:

```sh
HERE=$(realpath -s "$(dirname  "$0")")
```

This does not change the current directory at time of invocation. Instead it turns the (wrong) relative path of `uppaal.jar` to an absolute path.